# Difference between "if I can be of any help" and "if I am of any help"

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

What is the difference between "if I can be of any help" and "if I am of any help"?  For example:

> Please let me know if I **can be of** any help.

or

> Please let me know if I **am of** any help.

This really beats me. All I can say is both seem to offer help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Please let me know if I can be of any help.

This is an offer of help before you have done anything - a **future possibility**.

> Please let me know if I am of any help.

This is asked after you have started helping, to check whether what you are doing is **currently** useful.

Here is a further possibility:

> Please let me know if I have been of any help.

This is asked after you have finished helping, to check whether what you have done **was** useful.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is a polite, idiomatic way to offer help. It basically means "please, let me know if there's anything I can help you with".

The other one seems to be asking for *feedback* - "please, let me know if I am (currently) helpful". I personally wouldn't use it to offer help, even if it can be parsed this way if you stretch your interpretation a bit.